# Slight graphics bugs

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, beta-sites

Some slight graphical niggles with our lovely Beta theme:

[image]

[image]

Comment: A circle, perhaps drawn free-hand, would help in identifying the anomaly...

Comment: I hope that clears things up

Comment: I'm moving this to Meta, the Beta theme has been used on over forty other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the 28th October 2011 the [new profile pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59446/157163) have been rolled out on all Stack Exchange sites which appears to have fixed the reputation icons.

Browsers render webpage's differently. When reporting a graphic bug, I recomend you mention your browser and version number. A list of supported browsers can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/157163).